# Java - Want getKeyCode to only register once

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a little game. I'm using `getKeyCode` to move my character but the thing is that I don't want you to be able to keep moving if you hold in the button. Is there anyway I can use `getKeyCode` to only register on the first click and then won't register until I release the button and press again?

```
else if (event.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_UP)
{
    spelare1.setLocation(spelare1.getX(),spelare1.getY()-50);
}
```

This is how it currently looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing KeyEvents. `VK_UP` is the *up arrow key*. Use `KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED` to react on a released key.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a boolean indicating whether the key is currently pressed. Then you can react once after each press, like in this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        private boolean pressed;
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            pressed = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (!pressed) {
                System.out.println("Key pressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
                pressed = true;
            }
        }
    });

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Depending on your needs, you might want to have a separate state for each key, or just one shared state.